# Browser Width and Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code to show the width and height for the viewport, but not the actual window size.

Any idea how I can get the window size?

Comment: i have tried and works with me: http://jsfiddle.net/hL8Zc/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by window size? because the functions that you are using should return the correct values

Comment: The function is correct for the viewport width and height (inside the browser), but not the window width and height (the actual width and height of the browser).

Comment: You're talking about the desktop window? Why do you think you can do anything but guess that? That's really outside of the "window" context of the page you're within.

Comment: Ah. Is there a way to get the width and height (which I already have) and toggle the toolbars on and off.

Comment: Not realistically. You can [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) a new window and use `toolbars=no` in the window features list (or the opposite). You're still left to the devices of the specific browser (and user). It could be forced into a tab, for instance, and you can't monkey with a window your code doesn't open (and may not be allowed to do so even in ones you do open).

Comment: Gotcha. Interesting. I'll take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think what you want the document `width` and `height`

Try using `$(document).height()` and `$(document).width()` to get the page width and height.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JvGZr/2/

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I've tried document and window but it didn't work.

Comment: @user1658756 Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot get the size of the browser panels.

The closest you can get is if the user has maximized the window, you can take the screen size and subtract the window size, and it will leave you with the size of the toolbars.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to get the width and height (which I already have) and toggle the toolbars on and off.